# PySpark - Join dataframe by time intervals

Tags: python, join, pyspark, left-join, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes

```
df_fruit= spark.createDataFrame([("Apple", "10:00"),("Orange", "12:35"),("Apple", "11:36"),("Apple","12:48"),("Pear","11:00")], ["Fruit", "Time"])
```

This dataframe stores when a fruit should be eaten.

I have an additional dataframe which stores when exactly a fruit was eaten by a person as well as how many cals, and kg's was ingested.

```
df_calories= spark.createDataFrame([("Apple", "10:02", "86g", "1cal"),("Orange", "12:39", "75g", "14cal"),("Apple", "10:04", "9g", "47cal"),("Apple","12:46", "25g", "9cal"),("Orange","12:33", "75g", "2cal")], ["Fruit", "Time", "Weight", "Calories"])
```

I need to join both tables by Fruit but also in time intervals of 5 mins. Since ingestion is flexible 5 mins either way from recommended time.

This is the expected result.

```
+------+-----+-----+------+--------+
| Fruit| Time| Time|Weight|Calories|
+------+-----+-----+------+--------+
| Apple|10:00|10:02|   86g|    1cal|
| Apple|10:00|10:04|    9g|   47cal|
|Orange|12:35|12:39|   75g|   14cal|
|Orange|12:35|12:33|   75g|    2cal|
| Apple|11:36| null|  null|    null|
| Apple|12:48|12:46|   25g|    9cal|
|  Pear|11:00| null|  null|    null|
+------+-----+-----+------+--------+
```

The join type should be a left join i.e. all of `df_fruit` must be maintained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming time interval is fixed to 5mins,we can create start time and end time for each fruit in df_fruit and join them as,

```
>>>import datetime
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

>>> maxtimeudf = F.udf(lambda x : (datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%H:%M')+datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)).strftime('%H:%M'),StringType())
>>> mintimeudf = F.udf(lambda x : (datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%H:%M')+datetime.timedelta(minutes=-5)).strftime('%H:%M'),StringType())

>>> df_fruit = df_fruit.withColumn('starttime',mintimeudf(df_fruit['Time'])).withColumn('endtime',maxtimeudf(df_fruit['Time']))
>>> df_fruit.show()
+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Fruit| Time|starttime|endtime|
+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Apple|10:00|    09:55|  10:05|
|Orange|12:35|    12:30|  12:40|
| Apple|11:36|    11:31|  11:41|
| Apple|12:48|    12:43|  12:53|
|  Pear|11:00|    10:55|  11:05|
+------+-----+---------+-------+
>>> df = df_fruit.join(df_calories,((df_fruit.Fruit == df_calories.Fruit) & (df_calories.Time.between(df_fruit.starttime,df_fruit.endtime))),'left_outer')
>>> df.select(df_fruit['Fruit'],df_fruit['Time'],df_calories['Time'],df_calories['Weight'],df_calories['Calories']).show()
+------+-----+-----+------+--------+
| Fruit| Time| Time|Weight|Calories|
+------+-----+-----+------+--------+
|Orange|12:35|12:39|   75g|   14cal|
|Orange|12:35|12:33|   75g|    2cal|
|  Pear|11:00| null|  null|    null|
| Apple|10:00|10:02|   86g|    1cal|
| Apple|10:00|10:04|    9g|   47cal|
| Apple|11:36| null|  null|    null|
| Apple|12:48|12:46|   25g|    9cal|
+------+-----+-----+------+--------+
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks so much! however, I am having this issue `ValueError: year=1899 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900`
I think it because some times in the dataframe at 12:00. There is a way to set the year to any other year?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue. can you give me the data which throws this error. ?